# Pause setInterval, but resume it's position once it has been stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval

I've created a very simple timer using JavaScript. However, at the moment there is no way to pause the `setInterval()`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/hyZ3L/)

HTML:

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="show">0</div>
<input type="text" name="count" class="count">
<div class="submit">submit</div>
```

JS:

```
var submit = $('.submit');
var bar = $('.bar');
$('.submit').click(function () {
    var count = $('.count').val();
    var newCount = parseInt(count);
    var i = 0;
    var timeChange = 1000;
    console.log(newCount);
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        console.log(i);
        $('.show').text(i);
        if (i == newCount) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log('Finished!');
            bar.delay(2000).animate({
                width: '0%'
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000)
    bar.animate({
        width:'100%'
    }, newCount * 1000, 'linear');
});
```

Is there a way I  can pause the setInterval, but resume it's position once it has been stopped?

Comment: Can you not just call `clearInterval(timer)` and `setInterval` again to start?

Comment: You don't have a pause button - what would cause it to pause? Also, why are you using a div as a submit button? (That's not usable via the keyboard so is an accessibility fail.)

Comment: nnnnn, the div as submit is just temporary, for some reason the jsfiddle wasn't happy with my input box and form tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In my opinion) The simplest way to pause a `setInterval()` is to add a boolean `paused` variable and then in the interval callback simply check that variable and return immediately if paused. That way you don't have to worry about resetting the state of any other variables; the interval itself keeps going even when "paused", but your function doesn't do anything when paused.

By default jQuery doesn't really have a way to pause an animation once begun (though there are several plugins that allow this), but instead of a single call to `.animate()` like you have to extend the progress bar to 100% width you could move the `.animate()` call inside the `setInterval()` callback and animate it one step at a time - with a linear animation that looks the same, but allows a pause at each step.

You don't say what would trigger the pause, but assuming you wanted to add a pause button then this would work:

```
var paused = false;
$("#pause").click(function () {
    paused = !paused;
});

var bar = $('.bar');
$('.submit').click(function () {
    // consider adding clearInterval(timer); here so that you don't have
    // two or more timers going if the user clicks submit multiple times,
    // and move the `var timer` declaration to just before this function
    var newCount = parseInt($('.count').val(), 10);
    var i = 0;
    var timeChange = 1000;
    console.log(newCount);
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (paused) return; // do nothing when paused
        i++;
        bar.animate({
            width: 100 / newCount * i + '%'
        }, 1000, 'linear');
        console.log(i);
        $('.show').text(i);
        if (i == newCount) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log('Finished!');
            bar.animate({
                width: '0%'
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hyZ3L/1/

Note that if you're using `parseInt()` on user-entered data you really should add the `,10` second parameter to ensure it is parsed as base 10. And you should add some code to validate that the user actually entered a number, or your timer will go on forever. And you may want to add `clearInterval()` at the point I commented above.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful. Would you have a resource for the second parameter(base of 10)? I'm very poor at understanding even the basics of math.

Comment: Also, I've tried putting in clearTimer as you suggested (for multiple clicks) -- but the variable hasn't been called yet. Would there be an alternative?

Comment: Use of `parseInt()` is explained [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). If you don't understand maths very well I suggest you simply _always_ specify the second parameter of `parseInt()` as `10`, as in `parseInt(someString, 10)`, because you're not likely to ever want to use anything other than base 10 and this will avoid having `parseInt()` decide that a number should be treated as octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, sorry, yes, you'd need to declare the `timer` variable outside the click handler, so put `var timer;` above the `$('submit').click(...` line and then within the function delete the `var` and just say `timer = setInterval(...`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hyZ3L/2/ - though you may want to ignore subsequent clicks until the previous interval is cancelled, in which case you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/hyZ3L/3/